# Top of the minute stream with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

For a calendar alert use case, I need to create an Observable that emits every minute at the top of the minute (0th second of every minute), every 15 minutes (0th second of 0 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 45 minutes etc)

The timer service checks every minute and creates an alert (reminders etc)

I tried the following:

```
//get 59th second of this minute and start an observable timer
var  date : Date = moment().endOf('minute').toDate();
const source = Observable.timer(date, 60000);

source.subscribe(val => console.log("New Minute: " + moment().format()));
```

This works and emits on top of every minute but the seconds drift and within the hour the emission is at 47th second.

I realize that the best way to do this would be to emit every second and check if the second is 0 but I am not sure how to do that using Observable.

edit: This is an Angular 2 app.

Comment: I'm curious why you opted for subscriber/observer instead of a simple cron?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is an angular 2 application

Comment: I understand that, I am just curious as to why you would use such a roundabout method to get what basically amounts to a timer that goes off every half hour.

Comment: I must be missing something very basic. Could you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I wasn't criticizing or anything like that. I'm just curious about what led to the choice. Sorry that wasn't clear. It wasn't my intention to confuse.

Comment: No offense taken. I have multiple calendar events that keep track of when users need to be alerted. When an event is [15] minutes away, I start a countdown timer that shows up on the screen. I felt like this is the best way to do this with a stream of time triggering events at certain intervals/conditions. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem a bit convoluted but you could just start an `observable.timer` to run once per second and then filter for `seconds === 0`. Like this:

```
  const source = Rx.Observable.timer( 1000, 1000)
                .map(x => moment())
                .filter(mom => mom.seconds() === 0);

  source.subscribe(m => console.log(m));
```